# Upgrade Xcode 8.3.1 to Xcode 9

Tags: xcode, upgrade, apple-developer

I am not having paid Apple Developer Account and using Xcode 8.3.1, Xcode 9 is released recently and i want to upgrade my Xcode but only download option is available. is it possible to upgrade or i have to download new one separately.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Open AppStore than Purchased and find the Xcode.It will have option of `INSTALL` click on this.It will update Xcode to latest one.In my case updated to Xcode9.

Appstore after installation.

[image]